# Can't get jq command working from bash script with a key containing a dot

Tags: bash, jq

I have a json file with keys containing dots.:

```
{
"a": "b",
"foo.bar": true 
}
```

I want to get the value of certain keys using jq from a script. Running from the command line works:

```
jq -r ".[\"foo.bar\"]" sample.json
true
```

And I'm basically doing the same thing from a bash script (except for some string expansion behaviour I can't grasp).:

```
#!/bin/bash

file="sample.json"
key="foo.bar"
command="jq -r \".[\\\"$key\\\"]\" $file"
# jq -r ".[\"foo.bar\"]" sample.json : Works in the console

result=$($command)
statusCode=$?
echo "result $result, statusCode $statusCode"
# result .["foo.bar"], statusCode 0
```

I tried more combinations, such as using single quote outer delimiter for the jq or replacing "\" with "\x5C", and didn't find a working formula.

I can't replace/remove the dots in the json files because they are an external dependency.

Environment is bash 3.2, jq 1.6, mac os 11.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want two things you missed:

1. Pass your key as an `--arg name value` to `jq`.
2. Tell `jq` to report boolean value as status-code with `-e` or `--exit-status`.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

file='sample.json'
key='foo.bar'

result="$(
  jq --exit-status --raw-output --arg k "$key" '.[$k]' "$file"
)"
statusCode=$?
printf 'result %s, statusCode %d\n' "$result" "$statusCode"
```